# How to find mathematical model of a wheeled robot (to compute robot's trajectory at given time steps) including its kinematic

Tags: motion-planning, path-planning, geometry

**I would like to learn, how to find proper kinematic model of robot in mathematical form.**

For example:

I would like to create a model of a car, from which I could compute its position and rotation at given time steps.

Assume Ackerman steering system and knowns *l, w* (see picture)

Inputs are:

1. constant speed of wheels's rolling
2. variable velocity of wheels's steering

I found similar problem here [path-of-a-simple-turning-car](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055263/path-of-a-simple-turning-car). I think principal is the same, **but my question is what are the steps to find proper model**. I understand the equations in the link, but I would not be able to make them on my own and slight change in geometry of robot  would confuse me.

[image: car]

Comment: Have you looked at Gazebo? gazebosim.org

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lecture from Georgia Tech's Control of Mobile Robot's Coursera class derives the bicycle model; https://youtu.be/cQWhYCrK06M

Comment: Thank you for an answer.